# Graph based on pairwise comparison

Tags: python, r, plot, graph, visualization

I compared two list of terms:

```
list1:
Post-term birth
Preimplantation genetic diagnosis
Preimplantation genetic screening
Preterm birth
```

and

```
list2
sodium                                      
ethylene                        
benzenesulphonic acid, compound with N-methylcyclohexylamine                        
dimethanol
```

(*these are short versions*)
I retrieved all possible combinations using: `combis = list(itertools.product(list1, list2))`
. Then I used these combinations (e.g. `Post-term birth AND sodium` ) to search a database ([PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed) in this case). I counted the number of hits found and saved these in a ditcionary, which looks like this:

```
{'sodium AND Post-term birth': 0, 'sodium AND Preimplantation genetic diagnosis': 15, 'sodium AND Preimplantation genetic screening': 5, 'sodium AND Preterm birth': 499, 'sodium AND Pro-nuclear transfer': 0, 'sodium AND Recurrent spontaneous abortion/miscarriage': 11, 'sodium AND Reproductive surgery': 1000, 'sodium AND Severe ovarian hyperstimulation syndrome': 10 ..... etc
```

I was wondering if it is possible to combine these pairwise results into a graph. So e.g. looking at these terms:

```
sodium AND Post-term birth': 0, 'sodium AND Preimplantation genetic diagnosis': 15
```

And create something like:
[image]
*(offcourse I want this to be generic so I can use it for alle the terms (not only for these compounds and phenotypes))*

Extra points which can be considered:

- **If this is not possible in Python maybe it is in R?**
- **I can easily adjust the data structures e.g. replacing the dictionary to a nested list if this is easier**

Comment: It's possible, but StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Investigate the `networkx` library for Python. After that, come back to us with a specific problem when you're stuck.

Comment: I'm not looking for code (maybe a simple example) but just for the best language to use / libraries etc. @aryamccarthy

Comment: That's officially outside of the scope of StackOverflow. I don't mean to be obstinate. Still, I've given you a pointer. Check it out and then update the question with what you've tried.